# MySQL jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem that is driving me crazy, im really not used to working with mySQL databases and i really need some help with this. I want to connect to my MySQL database to run querys and eventually be able to load data in to the database and measure the time consumed for loading, querying etc, so i can compare the performance on different kinds of databases.
I THINK i got the forName to work, but now its complaining about the dbUrl.
Can someone explain to me what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.*;


public class jdbcdemo{

public static void main(String args[]){
String dbtime;
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Meeting";
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String query = "Select * FROM customer";

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("user", "student");
properties.put("password", "ingan86");

try {

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl,properties);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while (rs.next()) {
dbtime = rs.getString(1);
System.out.println(dbtime);
} 

con.close();
} 
catch(SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}


}  

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'student'@'localhost' (using password:   YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:798)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3700)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1203)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2572)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at jdbcdemo.main(jdbcdemo.java:22)
```

Comment: can you connect from command line using that login/password combination?

Comment: Try explicitly adding a `student`@`localhost` user and granting it permissions, as in the @Reimus' answer.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: "complaining about the dbUrl" doesn't tell us anything. Without knowing what the *actual* problem is (like, the error message or stack trace) all anyone can do is guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the user `student` has sufficient privileges to use your database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON Meeting.*
TO student@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'ingan86';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers! I figured it out, i just changed the user from "student" to "root" :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a far shot but I have faced this once. Check your host file. See if 127.0.01 is mapped to localhost.

Lookup - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)